# Join in SQL where a part of values are matching

Tags: sql, psycopg2, psql

I have 2 tables one contains (slug) column and the other contains (path) column

the path contains a directory then the slug from the 1st table as following:
/article/{slug} ,i.e part of value only matches the other table.

How to join both tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `like`:

```
select . . . 
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.path like '%/' || t2.slug
```